# Any way to recreate this procedurally and random?

Tags: materials, procedural, mathematics, texture-coordinates

I've recently been trying to create a personal library of node groups and materials to get a better understanding of blenders material nodes, but I'm a bit stumped on how to recreate this

[image: 1]

I'm trying to use something like this to create coordinates for a material I'm working on, as well as add a gap with a dynamic profile like the brick texture by using a color burn and color dodge. I also mocked a graph of the values in desmos to help in understanding

[image: 2]

Comment: Is there a pattern for the values? should it be random? should it be random but rounded to integers?

Comment: I'm trying to make it at least look like it's random, it doesn't need to be rounded to integers, but i wanted to be able to set a minimum length and a maximum length for them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be possible to extract the right information from Blender's own Voronoi texture, but you'd have to call it twice, and I'm not sure it would save any nodes. (Someone will correct me now...)

So this is a roll-your-own 1D Voronoi. That is to say, it is per-cell random, not full-space random. The method:

- Divide X into unit cells
- Seed a random 0-1 number for each cell using the cell's index (its minimum coordinate).
- Consider the random number to be the offset of a feature-point `F` for that cell, from its minimum X.

Now, for any shading-point `P`, we know the location of `F` in its own cell, and the location of the feature-point `F'` in the previous cell. That's enough.

If we're to the right of `F`, then `f(x) =  P.x - F.x` . If we're to the left of `F`, `f(x) = P.x - F'.x`.

That all takes more plumbing than you might expect, and unhelpfully, in the illustration, I've called `F` *P_this*, and `F'` *P_prev*:

[image]

You may be able to trim it down..

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a bunch, i had a sneaking suspicion that Voronoi could have led me to the solution

Comment: @Autumn I've often wondered how to go about procedural randomly-packed rectangular tiles, without any corners cut out of any of them, myself.... I still haven't worked that out.